# Why does my exported file have transparent faces and jumbled texture?

Tags: texturing, export, faces, normals, .fbx

I completed a project and exported it as an fbx. I open the file in a new blender project to test it and the faces are transparent. I have searched all over the internet to figure out why this is happening. Here's what I've done so far:

- I have checked that my normals are facing correctly. I have went into the original file and I have exported with normals being flipped both ways and the issue persists.
- I have tried exporting with backface culling on **AND** off and the issues persist.
- I have redone my textures and UV mapping to make sure that each step is done properly and the issue persists.

**Here are some gifs of my issue**:

So this link shows what my project looks in the original file BEFORE export: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JrFm.jpg

This link shows what the project looks like EXPORTED (as fbx) AND OPENED in a new blender project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxbkz.jpg

(***REMOVED BLEND FILE LINK BECAUSE THE ISSUE IS SOLVED***)

So that you understand what this project is, this is supposed to be an avatar asset for VRchat. So I want to be able to share this file to others and have it look the same way as before I exported it.

Comment: Can you provide the blend file or the fbx file?

Comment: I can yes. How do I do so on this site? This is my first time asking a question here.

Comment: If it's the blend file, you can use https://www.pasteall.org/blend/ and add the link to your question.

Comment: ok i tried pasteall and it kept saying that my file isnt a blend file..which it is so idk. i just did it on google drive. hopefully that works. i have edited it to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I deleted this since I was receiving any help. But after playing around with some settings, I figured it out:

**I had to change the blend mode to "Opaque" for each material AND turn on backface culling for EACH material within the NEW project.**

For some reason, when I opened the exported file into a new project, Blender would automatically make the blend mode "Alpha Hashed". I don't know if there's a way to keep settings during export so that when I share this file, people do not have to fix these settings themselves, but for now, it is solved.

Hope this helps! Happy Blending! :)